# Convert ASP.net page into byte[]

Tags: asp.net, arrays

How can we convert an Asp.net web page into byte[]. I need to export my web page into PDF file.

Comment: If you request it as data, you get it as a byte array, but how would that help you to export it as a PDF file?

Comment: Do you need a byte[] or a .PDF?